# VBA Change Line Color To Be the Same As the Dashed Line

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to change the line of my fullseries sourcedata rangey3.I'd like rangeInvNorm to be a regular solid line and rangeInvFore to be dashed the same color.

I tried using:

```
.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(56, 182, 75)
.MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(56, 182, 75)
```

to no avail but it does work for the forecasted values.

My code is:

```
Set rangexMonth = Worksheets("DATA").Range(Cells(lRow - 14, 1), Cells(lRow, 1))
' Inventory
Set rangeInvNorm = Worksheets("DATA").Range(Cells(lRow - 3, 7), Cells(lRow - 14, 7))
' Inventory Forecast
Set rangeInvFore = Worksheets("DATA").Range(Cells(lRow - 14, 12), Cells(lRow, 12))


Sheets("Report").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
With ActiveChart
    .SetSourceData Source:=rangeInvNorm
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "Inventory"
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = rangexMonth
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
    .ChartTitle.Delete

With .SeriesCollection(2)
    .Name = "Inventory (Forecast)"
    .Values = rangeInvFore
    .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSysDot
    .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 189, 69)
    .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 189, 69)
End With
```

I'm trying to make the blue line the same color as the dashed line:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/KjjoKq1]

Comment: Start [recording a macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b), change the series color manually, stop recording the macro, inspect it.

Comment: Try using `.FullSeriesCollection(2)`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad That did not work.